# BootOrder in efibootmgr does not show OS-specific options

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, uefi

How can I set Ubuntu/GRUB as the active default boot option? My computer automatically boots to Windows.

Here is image of the `efibootmgr` output:

[image]

I'm running HP Envy dv6 with Intel Core i7 and I want to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am curious to know who down-voted on this question. Simply pasting the output would have been better, I agree, but apart from that this question shows another issue that I myself am seeing for the first time. Also the usage of efibootmgr and the multiple Ubuntu lines in the output show that the OP invested more effort than the average user here around.

Answer (score 0):

Wooo. EFI.

When you initially boot up your computer, enter the BIOS. In there, you want to find the boot order. It's usually called `Boot Order` or `Startup Order`.

Once you have found that, move the Ubuntu entry to the top of the list.

---

Your computer may also have a "Select Boot Device" feature. If it does (and you can access it), you can also select Ubuntu for a one-time boot.

Answer (score 0):

```
BootOrder: 3001,3002,3003,3004,3006,3007,2001,2001,2002,2003
```

This looks odd. You have a lot of active entries (all that have an asterisk), yet only device-specific loaders show up in the boot order. This may indicate that this firmware cannot boot or simply ignores OS-specific loaders.

Usually the entry created during installation is added as the first option in the boot order. So at least one of the Ubuntu entries should have been in first place (another hint that this firmware might be crippled :( ). `BootCurrent: 0002` though actually is Ubuntu and should should work! (…or this may be the 3rd hint that this firmware is crippled.) You can still try to change the order in the firmware settings, if that does not help you would need to install a default boot loader on the ESP in `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi`.

I have written about EFI default boot loaders in a few answers here at this site, but I am still in preparation phase for some better answers that will hopefully improve this situation for users facing this issue (non-business laptops seem to be more and more affected by this), sadly I don't have much time currently.

Rod Smith has some good articles about EFI on his page:

- [Gummiboot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/gummiboot.html)
- [Dealing with Secure boot - Section: Using the Linux Foundation's PreLoader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html)

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows 8. Open command prompt with administrative privileges. Then type the following command

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

This will replace Windows boot manager with Grub. Hope this helps.